# Multiple values RewriteMap prg

Tags: python, apache, http, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I'm not able to pass multiple values through a RewriteMap prg. This is what I have:

```
RewriteMap encrypt "prg:/bin/python2.7 /var/www/encrypt.py"
RewriteRule /secure ${encrypt:%{LA-U:ENV:email}} [P]
```

I am able to pass just one variable from the header, but not more than two.Any help would be appreciated it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteMap only takes one key string as a parameter, but you can append multiple things to the key. This is what I ended up with:

```
RewriteRule /secure http://website.com/${encrypt:%{LA-U:ENV:uid};%{LA-U:ENV:givenname};%{LA-U:ENV:surname};%{LA-U:ENV:email}}
```

The semicolon act as a separator to be used later to split the string.